# Population OLS coefficient in simple regression?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

The population OLS coefficient for some $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^d, Y \in \mathbb{R}$ for the model $Y = \beta’X + e$ is defined as
$$
\beta =\mathbb{E}[X_iX_i']^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X_iY_i]
$$
and if $X$ is a scalar random variable, the commonly shown formula for simple regression is
$$
\beta = Var(X_i)^{-1}Cov(X_i,Y_i)
$$
But from the more general first equation, shouldn’t this be
$$
\beta = \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]^{-1} E[X_i Y_i] 
$$
instead? Where is the variance / covariance coming from? (I.e. how do you derive that popular variance covariance formula from the more general vectorized version)?
I am clearly missing something, but I can’t seem to see what is happening to the extra terms (i.e. since $Var(X) = E[X^2] + E[X]^2$, not just $E[X^2]$). Is there something conceptually obvious that I am overlooking?

Comment: Hi: The first expression is a variance only if E(X) = 0 and the second expression is only a covariance if E(X) and E(Y) = 0. I'm not sure if that answers your question but covariance and variance, when written as expectations, are always calculated using the de-meaned random variable(s).

Comment: @markleeds Hey! I should’ve phrased my question more clearly, but my exact question is how do you derive the second equation (the commonly shown one) from the more general one (the first one).

Comment: Hi: I don't think I was clear either. The variance relation is  $E((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^{\prime}) = Var(X)$ but, if $\mu = 0$, then your relation holds. Does that make sense ? Same deal with covariance.

Comment: Just to show the second one: $E((X- \mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)) = Cov(X,Y)$ so if the means of $X$ and $Y$ are zero, then your relation is correct for covariance also.

Comment: Note that if you multiply out the first variance relation  that I wrote and take the expectation , you get $E(X^2) - \mu^2$. You have a plus in your i.e: since Var(X) = expression but it should be minus. Once you put the minus, it's the same as mine.  So, hopefully this answers your question regarding the first one leading to the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot get the results from a simple regression model because you did not include the intercept term in your model. 
The common formula for a simple regression model is derived from the model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \varepsilon$. This can be rewritten in matrix form as $Y = \beta^\top U + \varepsilon$, where $\beta = (\beta_0, \beta_1)^\top$ and $U = (1_n, X)$.  For simplicity, let's assume we observe $n$ tuples of $(x_i,y_i)$. The OLS estimation of $\beta$ yields $\hat{\beta}=(U^\top U)^{-1}U^\top Y$ and
\begin{align*} \begin{pmatrix} \hat{\beta_0} \\ \hat{\beta_1}\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} n  & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i & \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\end{pmatrix}^{-1} 
\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \dfrac{1}{n(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2  & -\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i & n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\end{pmatrix}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x} \\ \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix}\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x} \\ 
\dfrac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}\end{pmatrix} \ ,
\end{align*}
where $Cov(X,Y), Var(X)$ is the sample covariance and sample variance respectively.  We can also see that it holds true in a population sense (assumed both $X, Y$ are random variables):
\begin{align*} Cov(X,Y) & = Cov(X,\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon) \\ 
& = 0 + \beta_1Var(X) + 0 \\
\implies\beta_1 &= \dfrac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}\end{align*}

In your case, you assume that $X$ is a scalar, which means that your model is $Y = \beta_1 X +\varepsilon$, which is different from the classic simple regression model as the intercept term is missing. In this case, the OLS estimation is
\begin{align*}\hat{\beta_1} &= (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y \\
& = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \end{align*}
In a population sense, we still have
\begin{align*} Cov(X,Y) & = Cov(X,\beta_1 X + \varepsilon) \\
& = \beta_1 Var(X) \\
\implies\beta_1 &= \dfrac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. So I was remembering the formula incorrectly—appreciate the clarification.